# Batch File 'help switch'

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, command-line-arguments

I need help with creating the 'help switch' for my custom batch file. I want /? to work, but I am apparently missing or unaware of what would make my batch file work.

Is there a way create the use of switches similar to native windows tools.
[example like 'copy /v /y .....']

I would certainly like to make of such logic far better, and I am making use of 2 argument slots as is, assuming a default behavior outside of the switch.

I have looked, but I have missed what woudl enable this behavior for smarter use.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that batch programming is pretty primitive, so there is probably no
smarter ways of doing it.

The most general mechanism for handling parameters in the batch file is by
using the [SHIFT command](https://ss64.com/nt/shift.html)
to examine parameters one-by-one. In this way, the order of the parameters
does not matter.

The code would look something like:

```
:Loop
IF "%1"=="-switch" GOTO Continue
   •
   • Here your batch file handles -switch
   •
SHIFT
GOTO Loop
:Continue
```

For more of what is possible to do with batch files parameters see the article
[Command Line arguments (Parameters)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).